How to combine two object list by related field in Stream API
I have two lists of dto objects.
List bigDataList = [
  BigDataDto(id=1, key=null, timestamp=2024-05-24 15:38:00, value=10, status=null),
  BigDataDto(id=2, key=null, timestamp=2024-05-24 15:38:00, value=10, status=null),
  BigDataDto(id=3, key=null, timestamp=2024-05-24 15:38:00, value=10, status=null)
]

List smallDataList = [
  SmallDataDto(extraId=1, hmpid=a63ffce5-1d86-3afc-8b5a-97452f935632  status=ACTIVE)
  SmallDataDto(extraId=2, hmpid=1dbd3cd0-8382-3736-a9bd-f2cc78187dad  status=INACTIVE)
  SmallDataDto(extraId=3, hmpid=6ed7a21e-22a3-39a0-a83c-734e35625c67  status=DELETED)
]

I need to update null fields from BigDataDto by the value from SmallDataDto.
The objects have a related field, so if BigDataDto.id equals to SmallDataDto.extraId we can take the value SmallDataDto.hmpid and set it to BigDataDto.key also SmallDataDto.status and set it to BigDataDto.status.
As a result, I want to have updated objects list:
List resultDataList = [
    BigDataDto(id=1, key=a63ffce5-1d86-3afc-8b5a-97452f935632, timestamp=2024-05-24 15:38:00, value=10, status=ACTIVE),
    BigDataDto(id=2, key=1dbd3cd0-8382-3736-a9bd-f2cc78187dad, timestamp=2024-05-24 15:38:00, value=10, status=INACTIVE),
    BigDataDto(id=3, key=6ed7a21e-22a3-39a0-a83c-734e35625c67, timestamp=2024-05-24 15:38:00, value=10, status=DELETED)
]

I have implantation, but I don't like it. How can I improve this code and make it more Stream API style.
            for(BigDataDto bigData : bigDataList){
                Optional<SmallDataDto> findRelated = smallDataList.stream()
                        .filter(data -> Objects.equals(data.getExtraId(), bigData.getId()))
                        .findFirst();
                bigData.setKey(String.valueOf(findRelated.get().getHmpid()));
                bigData.setStatus(String.valueOf(findRelated.get().getStatus()));
            }


Assuming that within your smallDataList there is at most one SmallDataDto that is associated to a BigDataDto, you can:

Iterate through the elements of your BigDataList.
Filter the SmallDataList to find the only element (or no one) that is associated to your current BigDataDto.
Finally, for each SmallDataDto found (one or zero), set the BigDataDto's key and status with the values hmpid and status from SmallDataDto.

bigDataList.forEach(bigDataDto -> smallDataList.stream()
        .filter(smallDataDto -> smallDataDto.getExtraId() == bigDataDto.getId())
        .forEach(smallDataDto -> {
            bigDataDto.setKey(smallDataDto.getHmpid());
            bigDataDto.setStatus(smallDataDto.getStatus());
        }));

Here is also a demo at OneCompiler.
